# Can't use Rails on Ubuntu

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bash, ubuntu, path

I install Rails on clear Ubuntu 12.04 by this guide:
http://ryanbigg.com/2010/12/ubuntu-ruby-rvm-rails-and-you

All work well

Then I reboot system - rails was not found

But That placed in `~/.rvm/gems/ruby1.9.3-p448/bin/`

I'm trying to type: `PATH="$PATH:~/.rvm/gems/ruby1.9.3-p448/bin/"`

Then I have error: `"/usr/bin/env: ruby_noexec_wrapper"`

This file also in `~/.rvm/gems/ruby1.9.3-p448/bin/`

Tell, in which order should I edit PATH to start Rails correct?

Comment: I'm out of flags for today, but this is not really a programming question and better suited for SuperUser.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure this is in your `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_profile`

```
## RVM
if [[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]]  ; then source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ; fi
```

That will source the rvm script that sets up your `PATH` for you.

Answer (score 0):

Let's install RVM on our system using the following command.

```
$ bash < <(curl -s https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/install/rvm)
```

Once the command is executed, we need to add a line to ~/.bashrc file which will load RVM .The above file responsible for setting up our bash session.

```
$ echo '[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"' >> ~/.bashrc
```